# How to all elements based on property that dont exist on another list

Tags: java

I have two SETs `fooSet` and `barSet` of different objects `foo` and `bar` with properties:

```
Class Foo { String name, Integer age }

Class Bar { String name }
```

I want to know ALL THE ELEMENTS of the `fooSet` where `name` does not exist in the `barSet`

I did multiple things but dont work. I don't know how to fix this issue

```
barSet.forEach(b -> fooSet.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(b.getName())));
```

Example:

```
[Foo: "Johnny", 28; Foo: "Travolta", 10; Foo: "Smith", 15]
[Bar: "Travolta"; Bar: "Smith"]
```

**I want to get Johnny**

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those one-liners in the other answers are probably doing their job, but they are not necessarily readable. You could also instead do the following.

First, create a `Set` with all `name`s of `Bar`, and *then* process all `Foo` objects:

```java
Set<String> names = barSet.stream()
    .map(Bar::name)
    .collect(Collections.toSet());

Set<Foo> result = fooSet.stream()
   .filter(foo -> !names.contains(foo.name()))
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the fooSet by removing all name that are not present in barSet :

```
fooSet.stream().filter(foo -> !barSet.stream().map(Bar::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(foo.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's not filtering anything. DOn't forget barSet is not Set<String> It's objects

Comment: This wouldn't quite work since `barSet` is of type `Set<Bar>` and `Set#contains(Object)` uses `Object#equals()` and/or `Object#hashCode()` so in your case `!barSet.cointains(foo.getName)` would always return true since there are no equal objects to a string.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, did not see that, then just map tour barSet<Bar> to barSet<String>, see my edited response

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for each entry through the barSet and look if any entry matches the name from the Foo-Object or rather you want to remove the entry from the set when there is no entry in the `barSet` with the same name:

```
String name = "Johnny";
Set<Foo> foos = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( new Foo( name, 28 ), new Foo("Smith", 20 ) ) );
Set<Bar> bars = Collections.singleton( new Bar( name ) );
foos.removeIf( foo -> bars.stream().noneMatch( bar -> bar.getName().equalsIgnoreCase( foo.getName() ) ) );
```